# Button height in Chrome breaks alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form like this:

```
<form class="searchbox">
    <input type="text" name="tx_ttnews[swords]">
    <button type="submit" name="search"><span>Search</span></button>
</form>
```

Then set height like this

```
.searchbox input[type="text"],
.searchbox button[type="submit"] {
    height: 40px;
}
```

In firefox, looks okay and aligned, but not in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the problem? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in Chrome nor Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your selector and it should works fine:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

If that won't work, apply some `line-height` to them. I couldn't produce this problem in Chrome though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<div>` around the 2 objects. Then set `max-height: 40px;`. That way it will have a set max height of well, 40px. if it still has the problem then, you shoud set the (vertical) alignment to either middle or center.